# VirtualBox XP SP3 guest doesn't run in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox

I have a .ova file(virtual machine export format) containing an XP SP3 VM and imported with VirtualBox 6.1.16 and the VM seems to boot but then hang up taking like 80% of CPU resources.
Also it seems never reach the point that populate the host RAM.
I need to run a really old program that runs only in 16bit and 32bit OS.
The virtualization is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Is Vbox the newest version? Are Guest Extensions installed (may have to wait until the machine runs)? Can you try this machine on another computer with Vbox?  XP SP3 works fine here on Windows 10 with VMware Workstation.

Comment: Windows 10 32-bit runs 16-bit software.  You don't need Windows XP unless this software does not support Windows Vista/7 at all.  It's unclear the reason you first attempted Windows XP instead of a newer version of Windows that is also 32-bit

Comment: What I would do?  Reinstall XP in Virtualbox and not try to import an old copy.  Takes very little effort to install XP.

Comment: @John The VM was running flawlessly in Windows 7 x64. The Guest extension, as far I know is for the guest OS but if can't even boot to desktop I think the problem is not that.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have W10 32bit license.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Reinstall XP is not the main problem. I have to do a lot of configuration before can use the program; that's I why I took what I thought it will be the short path. Also there's no guaranty that a new reinstalled XP will work; tut, yes, it seems I must to try at least.

Comment: @E_Blue - I am guessing that means you have zero Windows 10 licenses?

Comment: @Ramhound I have the host W10. As far I know it can't be used in two machines and also is an x64 license.

Comment: @E_Blue - Windows isn't licensed by 64-bit or 32-bit.  If you have a free Windows 10 license, then you can install a 32-bit installation of Windows 10.  Microsoft stopped that nonsense with Windows Vista.  If you want help getting Windows XP running on the VM we would need the VirtualBox log file.

Comment: @Ramhound I have not free W10 license; I have only one and I'm using it in the host PC. I have a W7 license that I stop using. How I can get the VB log?

Comment: Windows 7 also was simply licensed.  The same license could install 32-bit or 64-bit Windows 7.  If that is a free eligible license you should try Windows 7, the software might work, but if it doesn't then you know you need a Windows XP VM.

Comment: I would try making a new XP SP3 VM and see if that works. If it does use that as a base and move your software onto it.

Comment: @John Doesn't work. I'm trying to install XP and is way too slow and took like 90% of the assigned cores. Stupid W10. I was Happy with my W7.

Comment: Try a trial version of VMware Workstation. I have Windows XP SP3 running here and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my recommendations after a lot of trial and error:

1. Make sure VT-x/AMD-V hardware virtualization is enabled in your bios.
2. Make sure Hyper-V is not enabled, i.e. through Hyper-V itself, Antivirus like core isolation of Microsoft Defender, Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2), etc.
3. Choose under Settings -> General -> Basic -> Windows XP (32-bit)
4. Enable VT-x/AMD-V for your VM, i.e. Settings -> System ->

   - Motherboard -> PIIX3 Chipset, I/O APIC enabled
   - Processor -> PAE/NX and Nested VT-x/AMD-V enabled
   - Acceleration -> Interface: Default, Nested Paging enabled

Please note that if you installed Windows XP using only 1 CPU core, Windows will enable a uni-core kernel (= you can only use 1 core in the future). So you better use 2 or more cores while installing, then you can assign as many cores later as you want.

5. Select as graphic card: VBoxVGA. Please note that it does not support 3D acceleration under VirtualBox 6.1 and newer. Use an older Virtualbox version if you need 3D acceleration. Not sure, if it was fixed, but to enable 3d acceleration under older VirtualBox versions, you need to install the VirtualBox guest extensions in safe mode.
6. I did the installation of Windows without Sound card and added ICH AC97 later, after installation of VirtualBox guest extensions. If the VM does not really need sound, I disable the audio, since I gain like 8 seconds during boot. Otherwise sound works. I could not figure out the cause for the delay.

The Windows XP installation order that I used, was as follows:
Upgrade to SP3, maybe with the help of [NTlite](https://nliteos.com/)
VirtualBox guest extensions
Updates, e.g. [WSUS Offline Update](https://www.wsusoffline.net/)
manual installation of missing updates (hard to find, since the update function doesn't work any longer, also for IE8 with TLS1.2 upgrade)

Comment: VT-x/AMD-V  is disabled and greyed out, so the only I can enable, related to, is in the acceleration tab "Nested Paging enabled"

Comment: unpack the .ova file and take the hard disk and create a new virtual machine and attach that hard disk from the .ova file. If VT-x/AMD-V is greyed out under processor, check bios settings. Also there is something I read about but did not encounter on a new installation: Hpyer-V virtualization got enabled blocking VirtualBox from using it. Remove any Hyper-V, check Windows Security -> device security -> core isolation, and check disable hyper-v on boot with bcdedit (google disable hyper-v completely).

Comment: Yes! It work! The stupid Hyper shit was blocking the VT-x/AMD-V. Thank you dude.  I love you! A lot of good karma for you!